# Hello, my program jumps over the for loop, and I don't know why

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace c3
{
    class Program
    {
        static int sumaTotala;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int teza;
            int numberOfNotes;
            Console.WriteLine("Numar de note: ");
            numberOfNotes = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            List<int> numarDeNote = new List<int>(numberOfNotes);
            for (int i = 1; i < numarDeNote.Count + 1; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Introdu " + i + " nota: ");
                int x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                numarDeNote.Add(x);
                sumaTotala += x;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Teza : ");
            teza = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Media a rezultat " + NumberInput(numarDeNote, teza, numberOfNotes));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        static float NumberInput(List<int> numarNote, int notaTeza, int numarxd)
        {
            float part1 = sumaTotala / numarxd;
            float part2 = part1 * 3;
            float part3 = part2 + notaTeza;
            float part4 = part3 / 4;
            return part4;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't want people to be harsh, you need to start by reading [ask] and how to create a [mcve]. This is not your common forum where you dump code and people solve your problems. So please [edit] your question, write a proper title and explain what's the problem

Comment: Indexes in .NEt start with 0. 1 will never be smaler then 1. It is a good old friend - the off by one error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `numarDeNote.Count` starts at 0, and your `i` starts at 1, so the condition `i < numarDeNote.Count + 1` in the for-loop never becomes true. So the loop body is never executed.

Specifying a value when creating the list means that the initial list has room to grow for that many entries, but still initially there are no entries.

Comment: You might want to mention the integer division problem in the `NumberInput` function

Comment: Thanks but that is not related to the for-loop issue and I did not even look that far. The question and answer both stay the same without that piece of code.

Answer (score 1):

That constructor for List just sets the capacity
It still has a Count of zero until you add items

[List Constructor (Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw8e0z9z(v=vs.110).aspx)

Use

```
for (int i = 1; i < numberOfNotes + 1; i++)
{
```

Answer (score -2):

Constructor parameter in

```
List<int> numarDeNote = new List<int>(numberOfNotes);
```

is `Capacity`, not `Count` of the created list.

```
for (int i = 1; i < numberOfNotes + 1; i++)
{
  ...
```